# Swap two structure and two int using void pointers in function parameter

Tags: c, swap, void-pointers

In the below code, I am using a single swap function to swap two types of data. But I am getting lots of error.

Can anyone help me that where I am doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
```

//Structure definition which I am trying to swap.

```
struct swapNum
{
    int sal;
    char *c;
};
```

//The swap function which I am using to swap with void function parameters.

```
void swap(void *a,void *b, int size)
{
    if(size == sizeof(*a))
    {
        struct swapNum temp;
        memcpy(temp,a,sizeof(*a));
        memcpy(a,b,sizeof(*b));
        memcpy(b,temp,sizeof(*temp));
    }
    if(size == sizeof(int))
    {
        int *temp;
        *temp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = *a;
    }
}
```

The main driver part of program.

```
int main(void) {
    char a[10] = "vivek";
    char b[10] = "mishra";
    struct swapNum *A= malloc(sizeof(struct swapNum));
    struct swapNum *B = malloc(sizeof(struc swapNum));
    A->sal = 23;
    A->c = a;

    B->sal = 64;
    B->c = b;

    swap(&A,&B,sizeof(A));

    int x=10,y=20;
    swap(&x,&x,sizeof(b));
    printf("After swapping x : %d y: %d",x,y);

    return 0;
}
```

The errors which I am getting.

```
prog.c: In function 'swap':
prog.c:16:9: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'memcpy'
         memcpy(temp,a,sizeof(*a));
         ^
In file included from prog.c:2:0:
/usr/include/string.h:46:14: note: expected 'void * __restrict__' but     argument is of type 'struct swapNum'
 extern void *memcpy (void *__restrict __dest, const void *__restrict __src,
              ^
prog.c:18:30: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'struct     swapNum')
         memcpy(b,temp,sizeof(*temp));
                              ^
prog.c:18:9: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of 'memcpy'
         memcpy(b,temp,sizeof(*temp));
         ^
In file included from prog.c:2:0:
/usr/include/string.h:46:14: note: expected 'const void * __restrict__' but     argument is of type 'struct swapNum'
 extern void *memcpy (void *__restrict __dest, const void *__restrict __src,
              ^
prog.c:23:9: warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer
         *temp = *a;
         ^
prog.c:23:17: warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer
         *temp = *a;
                 ^
prog.c:23:9: error: invalid use of void expression
         *temp = *a;
         ^
prog.c:24:9: warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer
         *a = *b;
         ^
prog.c:24:14: warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer
         *a = *b;
              ^
prog.c:2
4:9: error: invalid use of void expression
     *a = *b;
         ^
prog.c:25:9: warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer
     *b = *a;
     ^
prog.c:25:14: warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer
         *b = *a;
              ^
prog.c:25:9: error: invalid use of void expression
         *b = *a;
         ^
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:33:36: error: 'struc' undeclared (first use in this function)
  struct swapNum *B = malloc(sizeof(struc swapNum));
                                    ^
prog.c:33:36: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for     each function it appears in
prog.c:33:42: error: expected ')' before 'swapNum'
  struct swapNum *B = malloc(sizeof(struc swapNum));
                                          ^
```

Comment: why not try with `void swap(struct swapNum *a, struct swapNum *b, int size)`?

Comment: why don't you print out what `sizeof(*a)` is, so you can see what the compiler thinks the size of a dereferenced void pointer is.

Comment: @yano If I use     void swap(struct swapNum *a,struct swapNum *b, int size) then this function will never be able to swap two integers.

Comment: Since you are getting compilation errors, you should post them.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `swap(&x,&x,sizeof(b));` really be: `swap(&x,&x,sizeof(int));`?

Comment: @jxh I posted errors

Comment: @bruceg sizeof(b) or sizeof(int) both are going to be same.

Comment: Your errors don't really match to code you have posted.

Comment: [fix code](http://ideone.com/apFhMy)

Comment: The `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time. The compiler will have no idea what the size of the target of a `void*`  pointer will be at run time. Why don't you just provide 2 functions? Even better, a swap operation for a `struct` or `int` is trivial, and can be done inline without any function.

Comment: @jxh Sorry, Edited the error part.

Comment: ... you do not even need `memcpy` to copy a `struct`. You just equate it, as you do with `int` (but cannot do with strings).

Comment: Can you focus on one of the compilation errors, and try to fix it yourself? If you don't understand what the error means, try posting a new question about the error, what you thought it meant, and how you tried to correct it.

Comment: I think the broad problem here is you're trying to write a one-size-fits-all function. If you want to swap structs, write a function that does that. If you want to swap ints, write a function that does that. A function should do one thing and do it well. If you've got a bunch of different data types you want to swap and don't want a unique swap function for each one, perhaps c++ with its inheritance and polymorphism is a better language choice. `void*` should generally be avoided. Besides, just because the size of something equals `sizeof(int)` doesn't mean it is an `int`, for example.

Comment: @vivek in main the size of b is a char[10] which is most likely 10.  So, unless you are on a system with 10 byte integers, I don't think that b and int are the same size.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

```
struct swapNum *A= malloc(sizeof(struct swapNum));
struct swapNum *B = malloc(sizeof(struc swapNum));
A->sal = 23;
A->c = a;

B->sal = 64;
B->c = b;

swap(&A,&B,sizeof(A));
```

`sizeof(A)` returns the size of a pointer, you need `sizeof(*A)` in order to get the correct size of the object.

And you don't want the address of `&A` and `&B` because they are already pointers, change to

```
swap(A,B,sizeof(*A));
```

The second problem is in the `swap` function:

```
void swap(void *a,void *b, int size)
{
    if(size == sizeof(*a))
    { ...
```

Compile with warnings:

```
warning: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to a void type
```

As suggested by @BLUEPIXY in comments, use a temporary:

```
void swap(void *a,void *b, size_t size)
{
    void *temp = malloc(size);

    if (temp) {
        memcpy(temp, a, size);
        memcpy(a, b, size);
        memcpy(b, temp, size);
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed it, but I am still getting errors.
    prog.c:16:9: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'memcpy'
             memcpy(temp,a,sizeof(a));
             ^
    prog.c:18:9: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of 'memcpy'
             memcpy(b,temp,sizeof(temp));
             ^
    prog.c:23:9: warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer
             *temp = *a;
             ^
    prog.c:23:17: warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer
         *temp = *a;
                 ^
    prog.c:23:9: error: invalid use of void expression
             *temp = *a;
             ^

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to implement a generic swap function that doesn't require `malloc` for your temporary:

```
void swap_by_bytes (void *a, void *b, size_t sz) {
    char tmp;
    char *ap = a;
    char *bp = b;
    while (sz--) {
        tmp = *ap;
        *ap++ = *bp;
        *bp++ = tmp;
    }
}
```

While byte by byte works fine, you might be able to improve things by copying word for word.

```
void swap_by_words (void *a, void *b, size_t sz) {
    unsigned tmp;
    char *ap = a;
    char *bp = b;
    while (sz >= sizeof(tmp)) {
        memcpy(&tmp, ap, sizeof(tmp));
        memmove(ap, bp, sizeof(tmp));
        memcpy(bp, &tmp, sizeof(tmp));
        ap += sizeof(tmp);
        bp += sizeof(tmp);
        sz -= sizeof(tmp);
    }
    if (sz > 0) swap_by_bytes(ap, bp, sz);
}
```

If the size is not a multiple of the word size, the remainder is swapped by bytes. Notice the use of `memmove` just in case `a` and `b` overlap.

Finally, you can use VLA if your platform supports it. However, C.2011 has made VLA an optional feature, so you have to test for its availability.

```
void swap (void *a, void *b, size_t sz) {
#ifdef __STDC_NO_VLA__
    swap_by_words(a, b, sz);
#else
    char tmp[sz];
    memcpy(tmp, a, sz);
    memmove(a, b, sz);
    memcpy(b, tmp, sz);
#endif
}
```